# Maneuverability calculation of a catamaran ship with azimuth thruster?

Tags: naval-engineering, ships

In a competition about ship prototype performance, my team decided to make a small catamaran ship with azimuth thrusters. This competition was originally about speed contest but due to COVID-19 it was replaced with report, video, and presentation contest. the competition required us to report maneuverability test using the IMO criteria, but it seems there is no criteria for catamaran with azimuth thrusters. I would like to know how should we calculate the maneuverability of our ship.

Comment: I'd suggest asking at https://www.boatdesign.net/forums/boat-design/.

Comment: A quick check didn't reveal anything about vessel type except that there is an exclusion for high-speed vessels. Just run the IMO tests as described in IMO [MSC 76/23/Add.1
ANNEX 6](http://www.imo.org/en/KnowledgeCentre/IndexofIMOResolutions/Maritime-Safety-Committee-%28MSC%29/Documents/MSC.137%2876%29.pdf)

Comment: see footnote page 5. " For ships with non-conventional steering and propulsion systems, the Administration may permit the use of
comparative steering angles to the rudder angles specified by this Standard. "